# Azure data factory pipeline failure email alerts to distribution list

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Azure data factory is not sending pipeline failure alerts to email distribution list.

It is able to send emails to individual email address but not to a distribution list.

Is there any special set up needed to send emails to distribution list here ?

Comment: I'm able to send the email alerts to distribution list. No need any special setup required.  Could you share the  screenshot of your setup?

Comment: Facing the similar issue, where email alerts are coming for individual email ids but not for DLs

Comment: Even I'm facing the same issue where alerts are going to individuals but not to DLs.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Here are my findings:

The catch is many a times, DLs(distribution lists) have **delivery restrictions**. So they won't accept emails from **external tenants**(in this case, Microsoft).

**Azure** emails are sent from the following emails:

- azure-noreply@microsoft.com
- azureemail-noreply@microsoft.com
- alerts-noreply@mail.windowsazure.com

So make sure you enable your DL(s) to receive emails from the above mentioned Microsoft email ids. There is no other special setup.